# Find pressure in a sinusoidal function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, optimization, quadratics

Tiffany is a model rocket enthusiast. She has been working on a pressurized rocket filled with laughing gas. According to her design, if the atmospheric pressure exerted on the rocket is less than 10 pounds/sq.in., the laughing gas chamber inside the rocket will explode. Tiffany worked from a formula $$p = (14.4)e^{-\frac{h}{10}}$$ pounds/sq.in. for the atmospheric pressure $h$ miles above sea level. Assume that the rocket is launched at an angle of α above level ground at sea level with an initial speed of 1400 feet/sec. Also, assume the height (in feet) of the rocket at time t seconds is given by the equation 
$y(t) = −16(t^2) + 1400tsin(α)$.

If the angle of launch is $α = 14°$, determine the minimum atmospheric pressure exerted on the rocket during its flight.

So I know I have to plug in the 14 for a but don't I need t as well to get the y(t) which is the height to find the pressure?

Comment: I get sinusoidal pressure. Sudaphed works well in the short run.

Comment: so you just have to plug in a and that gives you the pressure?

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** Mathematically, the "correct" input for sine is in radians. For ease of notation, assume degrees below.

You want to find maximal height by optimising $y(t)$ and then plugging in $h$. Note that $y'(t) = -32t + 1400\sin(14) = 0$, whence $t = 700\sin(14)/16$. So, $h = (1400\sin(14))^2\cdot(1/64)$. Then solve $p(h) = 14.4\cdot \exp(-h/52800)$, where we convert from **feet** to **miles**.

Comment: I get an extremely large number.

Comment: You should get a number less than $14.4$, since $\exp(-x)$ is a decreasing function, $h>0$ and $p(0) = 14.4$. What the number actually is - god knows.

Comment: by "exp" what do you mean? are you referring to "e"

Comment: Yes I am. I should note that they want you to convert $h$ from feet to miles. Look up the conversion and you get 5280 ft: 1 mile (I'm not American, so I didn't know this beforehand). You should get ~13.45 psi.

Comment: I cant seem to get the correct answer. Thank you though

Comment: @Sondra, what seems to be the problem?

Comment: When I try it I get h= 3584.729969 then I get p=13.45 I dont know if that is right. I got the same answer you got but it isn't right on my assignment

Comment: @Sondra, then what is the answer that your assignment gives.

Comment: it doesnt give me the answer. There is an alternative problem though and it is: p=(14.7)e^(-h/10) and y(t)==16t^2+1400sin(a)t. And the angle is give is 12 degrees. and the answer is 14.34

Comment: @Sondra, found the mistake. If you plug $t$ back in to the formula for $y(t)$ you get a factor of $1/64$ *not* $1/32$. Answer is ~13.92. Sorry for the algebra error.